# How to load the Revit addin from some specific folder?

Tags: c#, add-in, revit-api

I'm a new one in the development of the Revit addins. And I have one problem. Currently, Revit 2023 doesn't load my custom C# addin.

So, I have only one DLL file, that called MyTestAddin.dll. It's placed in the D:\WorkingProjects\MyTestAddin\x64\Debug\MyTestAddin.dll path.

It has the next class:

```
namespace MyTestNamespace
{
    public class MyTestAddin : IExternalApplication
    {
        public MyTestAddin()
        {
        }

        public Result OnStartup(UIControlledApplication application)
        {
            return Result.Succeeded;
        }

        public Result OnShutdown(UIControlledApplication application)
        {
            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
    }
}
```

And I create a MyAddin.addin file and place it in the C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\Revit\Addins\2023 folder. Here is the code of my manifest file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<RevitAddIns>
  <AddIn Type="Application">
    <Name>My Addin</Name>
    <Assembly>D:\WorkingProjects\MyTestAddin\x64\Debug\MyTestAddin.dll</Assembly>
    <ClientId>D784D34F-774E-4707-A313-B1C999A18544</ClientId>
    <FullClassName>MyTestNamespace.MyTestAddin</FullClassName>
    <VendorId>SomeVendor</VendorId>
    <VendorDescription>Some Description about Vendor</VendorDescription>
  </AddIn>
</RevitAddIns>
```

All looks as in the Revit guide. Assembly tag has a full path to the my DLL, FullClassName tag has a full class name including the namespace.

I added the full path to the Revit to the "Start external program" in the "Debug" option of the project. And I created a breakpoints inside the constructor and methods. But when I run my Revit from the Visual Studio, it doesn't catch any breakpoints. So it's looks like my addin isn't loaded to the Revit.

So I added some test code from some random guide that should create a new tab with a new panel and buttons:

```
// Create a custom ribbon tab
string tabName = "This Tab Name";
application.CreateRibbonTab(tabName);

// Create two push buttons
PushButtonData button1 = new PushButtonData("Button1", "My Button #1", "SomePath", "SomeCommand");
PushButtonData button2 = new PushButtonData("Button2", "My Button #2", "SomePath", "SomeCommand");

// Create a ribbon panel
RibbonPanel m_projectPanel = application.CreateRibbonPanel(tabName, "This Panel Name");

// Add the buttons to the panel
List<RibbonItem> projectButtons = new List<RibbonItem>();
projectButtons.AddRange(m_projectPanel.AddStackedItems(button1, button2));
```

But in this case I still don't see any new tab and panel in the Revit. And it still doesn't catch any breakpoints.

What is my problem? What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your external application implementation `MyTestAddin` is perfectly sufficient for the test. No further code is required or useful. The breakpoint in `OnStartup` should be hit when loading. The only remaining requirement is to specify the full add-in path in the `Assembly` tag in the add-in manifest, which you seem to be doing, and to place the add-in manifest in the Revit `AddIns` folder. For full details, check the [Revit API Developers Guide](https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2024/ENU/?guid=Revit_API_Revit_API_Developers_Guide_html) sections on [Add-In Integration](https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2024/ENU/?guid=Revit_API_Revit_API_Developers_Guide_Introduction_Add_In_Integration_html) and [Add-in Registration](https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2024/ENU/?guid=Revit_API_Revit_API_Developers_Guide_Introduction_Add_In_Integration_Add_in_Registration_html).

Comment: I've found the problem. In my example, I didn't write real data via the NDA, but in the correct manifest file, I have a vendor description that contains a "&" symbol. And this symbol makes a manifest incorrect. So Revit can't load it. I deleted this symbol and all works.

Comment: Glad to hear so. Thank you for the confirmation.